# Colour in a 5 by 5 grid, with evolution rules, so that the starting grid is the same as the output grid

Tags: pattern, visual, grid-deduction, cellular-automata

Colour in a 5 by 5 grid using the colours Red, Blue, Green and Yellow.

Each cell is considered to have 4 neighbours (to the left, right, above and below.) The grid wraps, so e.g. the top right is a neighbour of the bottom right and top left.

Produce a new grid as follows: if a cell is surrounded by 4 of the same colour, it turns (or remains) Red; if surrounded by 3 of the same colour and one different, it turns Blue; if surrounded by 2 of the same colour and any two other colours (e.g. G, G, R, Y or B, B, R, R) it turns Green; and if surrounded by 4 different colours, it turns Yellow.

[image: Colour puzzle example]

Question: other than a grid that's coloured all red, is it possible to
colour a grid so that the output, i.e. the grid that gets produced after one iteration, is identical to the starting grid? (You don't have to use all of the colours.) And, if not, can you prove that this is impossible?

I don't know the answer to this question, but after having spent some time trying to solve, I suspect it is impossible. (Hopefully I didn't miss something really obvious...) I'm hoping someone can supply a proof!

Comment: I'm curious how this arose.  Is it a pure puzzle, or did it grow out of some interesting research?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet I made this puzzle: https://www.reddit.com/r/PictureGame/comments/tfzsux/round_108628_milestone_cellular_automaton_puzzle/  for r/picturegame on Reddit and then this one is another variant in the same genre. However I couldn't post it on Picture Game as I didn't have a solution! So it's a pure puzzle.

Comment: I guess there would $4^5^2 = 1125899906842624$ possible grids.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: Found a Solution]

All the blue squares border 3 blue squares and 1 red square and all the red squares border 4 blue squares.

Comment: Nicely done! I puzzled for some time and never hit on this solution.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure this is the only solution beyond the all-red solution. Haven't been able to prove it though. I have managed to figure out that yellow can't be anywhere in a valid solution. Edit: Beyond trivial rotations of this one.

Comment: With MIP, I confirm there is no 3-color or 4-color solution.

Comment: I did a quick brute force search, and the three kinds of solution so far (this one, Magma's solution, and the all-red solution) are the only ones up to rotation/reflection/translation.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis What is "translation"?

Comment: @iBug It's on a torus, so you can cyclically shift everything (e.g. move everything down a row and put the bottom row on the top, or similarly with the columns).

Answer (score 18):

Here's one more solution that isn't the all-red one:

[image: green on a zigzag path repeating two right one down, blue otherwise]